# How to boot Ubuntu live on Windows 10 with fully encrypted drive?

Tags: live-usb, windows-10

How to boot Ubuntu live on Windows 10 with fully encrypted drive?

Do I have do turn of secure boot, disable kernel DMA protection and change to legacy boot each time? I am hoping I can find a way of not entering the BitLocker Drive Encryption recovery key.

Hopefully I am missing something obvious.

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop on the USB drive (made bootable using balenaEtcher).

If I shutdown, insert the drive and power up. It just goes boots to Windows 10.

**Edit**: If I hit F12 very rapidly during power up, it boots to Ubuntu. So, problem solved.

Comment: You've not provided any release details; but you should be able to boot Ubuntu *live* media without changing anything (*it may depend on your firmware though of which you gave no details*). The encrypted drive won't matter UNLESS you wish to access it to read/write data to it; that will of course require you to decrypt.  How you boot *live* media varies on devices; some I have require me to press & hold a key with device off; it'll then turn on & boot media.. others require me to press key after turned on .. ie. varies on device/firmware.

Comment: @guiverc What do you mean by release details?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server, Ubuntu 18.04... etc    though for some questions the specific upgrade level may also help (eg. 20.04, 20.04.1, 20.04.2, 20.04.3, 20.04.4....)   The more detail provided the more precise responses can be (the .point level provides kernel stack details as .2 & later HWE kernel stacks are involved esp. if it's a desktop and not server ISO/release).  FYI:  Details in title should also be repeated in question; some devices do not show title when page/question is being read.... we don't all use desktop systems (*or the same browser*)!

Comment: @guiverc How do I get firmware details? I am not exactly sure how firmware is relevant here?

Comment: Firmware is the *software* that is loaded on your particular device and controls how external media is booted.  It's machine specific put on the machine whilst built (ie. it's the BIOS/uEFI controls written on chips on the machine... it's usually capable of being updated (*esp. enterprise geared; less so consumer*) ; ie. fully upgraded machines won't boot 18.04.5 media which is why 18.04.6 media was created; but isn't always updated by the owners of hardware).  It's what requires me to press & hold a key on one box; but only press a key for another device on turning on to boot external media..

Comment: @guiverc Thanks, I did not realise you were referring to the BIOS (I am familiar with firmware/microcode). It turns out that if I keep hitting F12 (I tried this many times, not sure why it worked the last time) it boots directly to the Ubuntu. Should I delete the question?

Comment: I'd suggest writing your own answer; you may get an upvote & thus *rep* from it (you can get *rep* when/if you accept in your question in time anyway).  Maybe it'll be helpful to others!  (*it may also be closed as duplicate; I didn't look & just commented*).   *You can credit/refer to me in answer if you wish, but FYI I do find some faster boxes require me to reboot/hit-keys a number of times to strike them fast enough before they've started booting from the ssd*

Comment: @guiverc Thanks, I'll add an answer for what its worth. I don't care about the rep, I already have my SE T shirt :-). I did a few searches before asking. I tried booting many times hitting ESC, F2, F12, enter. None booted to Ubuntu prior to my last attempt. But, I know what to do now :-).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but may help someone.

I have Lenovo X1 Yoga 4th gen. in case that is relevant.

If I press the F12 key repetitively during power up it boots to Ubuntu.

I must not have been pressing it enough in my previous attempts (which included ESC, F2, F12, Enter, none of which accomplished the boot to Ubuntu).